# Facebook Recommend Ignoring og:title Until Page Refreshed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have the typical HTML5 implementation of the Facebook recommend button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    <? if ( $current_language == 'en' ): ?>
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    <? else: ?>
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js#xfbml=1";
    <? endif; ?>
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="share_button facebook" id="facebook">
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="80" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div>
</div>
```

The first time I click it, the popup preview box does not display the Title or Description.  I have the following info at the top of the page:
    Test

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="Test website." />
<meta name="keywords" content="test whatever" />
<meta property="og:title" name="Show this!" content="Show this!" />
```

If I leave the page, unrecommend the page from Facebook and return to the same page and press Recommend again, the title and description then appear.  The page shows one of thousands of db entries so the problem needs to be fixed.  I have tried putting the js function in jQuery(document).ready(function() - no luck.  I tried moving it to the bottom of the page - no luck.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Try running the url through the Facebook linter tool to force a reload of the cache - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: There are thousands of possible urls.  They are dynamically generated views of database content so the title/description are dynamic.  First time on a fresh link via linter shows the title and description correctly, it's the preview box from the page that won't show the information.

Answer (score 0):

From the example you gave, you are missing some required OG tags such as URL and image.  Also, do you have the prefix info on your head tag?

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# myspecialapp: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/myspecialapp#">
```